# Trying to make a script that auto fills a google doc with masked hyperlinks from a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

For example, I have a google sheet formatted like this with rows 1 to n

DOCUMENT TEXT   HYPERLINK   MASKING TEXT

&CAT JUMPS 1&   https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDYbg.jpg CAT JUMPS 1

&DOG JUMPS 1&   https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPnmv.jpg?1   DOG JUMPS 1

I have a google doc with information like this:

The cats are good jumpers &CAT JUMPS 1&. Dogs also jump high &DOG JUMPS 1&.

And I want the outcome to be like this:

The cats are good jumpers [CAT JUMPS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDYbg.jpg). Dogs also jump high [DOG JUMPS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPnmv.jpg).

I haven't done a google script before. I know how to make text into a hyperlink through scripts but I do not know how to make it look at the google sheet for the data or make it search for the document text and replace the text. Does anyone have some guidance on where I should be looking to figure out how to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reltated? https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/comments/elx0qh/trying_to_make_a_script_that_auto_fills_a_google/

Comment: That is me as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

Option 1

As mentioned in https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/comments/elx0qh/trying_to_make_a_script_that_auto_fills_a_google/, you can:

- You can use [`findText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern) to search using Regular Expression. For example, `body.findText("&.*&")`.
- Then for each found record, remove the leading and trailing `&`
- This will give you the lookup string. Use that to find the replacement values from the Google sheet
- Then use [`replaceText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) to replace strings

Example:

```
// get the lookup data from the spreadsheet
var lookupData = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("...").getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

// first row is header row
var lookupDataHeaderRow = lookupData.shift();

// get document body from the doc
var documentBody = DocumentApp.openById("...").getBody();

// we will continously search the document until there are no more found results
var searchResult = null;
while(searchResult = documentBody.findText("&.*?&", searchResult))
{
  // get the found element
  var foundElement = searchResult.getElement();

  // make sure it is a text type
  if(foundElement.getType() !== DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) continue;

  // get the text object of the found element
  var foundText = foundElement.asText();

  // extract the search string
  var documentText = foundText.getText().match("&(.*?)&")[1];

  // look for the documentText in the lookup data
  var foundLookupRows = lookupData.filter(function(row){
    return row[lookupDataHeaderRow.indexOf("DOCUMENT TEXT")] == documentText;
  });

  // make sure we found it in the lookup data
  if(foundLookupRows.length == 0) continue;

  // first replace the found text with the masking text of the first found row
  foundText.setText(foundLookupRows[0][lookupDataHeaderRow.indexOf("MASKING TEXT")]);

  // make it a hyperlink
  foundText.setLink(foundLookupRows[0][lookupDataHeaderRow.indexOf("HYPERLINK")]);
}
```

Option 2

Similar to above but:

- Go through each row in your Google sheet - the one with the lookup values
- Search the document for the DOCUMENT TEXT and make the appropriate replacements